# Installing R kernel with conda creates an unwanted addtional python kernel in Jupyter

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, conda

I created an R kernel to use in a Jupyter notebook with:

`conda create -n myrenv r-essentials -c r`

And when running Jupyter, in the menu to create a new notebook, i can see the choice of my new kernel `new` --> `R [conda env:myrenv]` but I also have the choice (among others) of `new` --> `Python [conda env:myrenv`].

How can I remove the latter environment from the list? I do not even know why python would be in my R environment.

Additional info:

`conda 4.5.11`

Answer (score 2):

`r-essentials` comes with python as well as the `jupyter_client` and the `ipykernel` packages which enables your jupyter to propose this R and thus the python installed as kernels in a notebook. ipykernel is mandatory for the jupyter to propose the R as a kernel and python is a dependency to ipykernel so...

I don't think you can remove python from the list of the kernels proposed. If you remove python from the conda environment, it also removes the ipykernel and the jupyter_client packages. All you can do is ignore it.

EDIT: found more infos

After looking into this since I wanted to do the same thing, it seems jupyter has a nice built-in program to do this:
Run
`jupyter-kernelspec list`
to list all available kernels. Then you can remove one with
`jupyter-kernelspec remove <kernel_to_remove>`
if you want to remove the kernel.
HOWEVER, it seems that you CANNOT remove the python3 kernel. Even though I ran:
`jupyter-kernelspec remove python3`
python3 still appears in the list and is still an available kernel in the notebook...

Comment: Thank you Eric, that makes sense for Python installed as well. I am still wondering if there is a way to remove the Python kernel associated to the R environment from the list while not removing the kernel itself.